# Button content not visible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am designing WPF form using Static Resource. I am using following code to design log in form.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.Login"
x:Name="Window"
Title="IntelCall | Login"
Width="640" Height="450" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DefaultButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16px"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,4.201" StartPoint="0.5,-3.792">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF001D4F"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF001D4F" Offset="0.515"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="2"             
                    BorderBrush="White"    
                    CornerRadius="5"            
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="640"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.495,1.258" StartPoint="0.496,-0.049">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF001D4F" Offset="0.249"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF5888DA" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF073A93" Offset="0.838"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="44.734" Margin="0,405.766,0,-0.5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.901,0.84" StartPoint="-0.164,0.84">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF001D4F" Offset="0.22"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF001D4F" Offset="0.878"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27.074" Margin="356.049,164.54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264.152" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="White" Padding="3"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27.074" Margin="356.049,224.54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264.152" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="White" Padding="3"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="Login ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200.978,158.154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft MHei" RenderTransformOrigin="0.694,0.477" Height="33.46" Width="93.723">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
    <Label x:Name="label_Copy1" Content="Login Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200.978,218.154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft MHei" RenderTransformOrigin="0.694,0.477" Height="33.46" Width="146.223">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButton}" x:Name="BtnLogin" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="356.049,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" Height="30.46">

    </Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButton}" x:Name="BtnReset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="495.201,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30.46" FontFamily="/WpfApplication1;component/Fonts/#Segoe UI">
        Reset
    </Button>
    <Image Margin="37.511,161.585,431.034,116.96" Source="Image/Phone.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-82.577"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Label Content="Intel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210.274,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft MHei"/>
    <Label Content="Call" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309.171,-4.444,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Kozuka Gothic Pro B" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="v1.0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401.201,27.266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Microsoft MHei"/>
</Grid>
```

My problem is, Button Content "Reset" and "Login" is not visible.
If I remove Static Resourse and gives all the property in button tag, button content works perfectly

Thank You for Helping, Here is URL for Output
http://prntscr.com/70lccv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ControlTemplate` you should have a `ContentPresenter` to display the content of the `Button`.

When you define the ControlTemplate, you should also define how the content of the button has to be displayed. You can use a`ContentPresenter` to display the content. You can also use a `TextBox` or `TextBlock` or `Label` etc to display the content of the button.

See below code.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="2"             
                    BorderBrush="White"    
                    CornerRadius="5"            
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: ok. Thank you murali. it's working. I'll accept your answer very soon.

Comment: Can you help me little bit here? why ContentPresenter is require here?